# Problem in designing a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am a beginner in android.I need to design my layout as given in the image(place 2 images in the 2 ends of the screen). But as per my code, its not showing as like the given image in my galaxy tablet. Please help.
My code is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/cam2"  
     android:onClick="@string/camera_click">
    </ImageView>



<TextView android:text="Camera" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
      android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="70dp">

<TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/TextView015"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>



<TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPicture1" 
            android:onClick="@string/gallery_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/photosgallery">
    </ImageView>

<TextView android:text="Gallery" android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="55dp" 
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPicture2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/contacts">
    </ImageView>



<TextView android:text="Contacts" android:id="@+id/TextView03"
      android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:gravity="right"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" >

<TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/TextView012"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>



<TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/TextView013"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPicture3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/process">
    </ImageView>

<TextView android:text="Processed" android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
    android:textColor="#000000"android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tablelayout.

```
<TableLayout>   <Tablerow> // 1st row 
  <LinearLayout> // with vertical Orientation
      // image view 1
      //textView 1
  </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout> // with vertical Orientation
      // image view 2
      //textView 2
  </LinearLayout>   </Tablerow> <Tablerow> // 2nd row
  <LinearLayout> // with vertical Orientation
      // image view 3
      //textView 3
  </LinearLayout>  <LinearLayout> // with vertical Orientation
      // image view 4
      //textView 4
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Linear Layout You can use Relative Layout. If you dont wannna 
use this layout you can stick to this Linear layout and check its orientation. But it is always better to use Relative layout because we can give margines and position to our widgets.

you can use this type of coding for managing ur UI

Answer (score 1):

Use *Relative layout* and set

```
android:layout_alignParentRight=true
```

or

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft=true
```

properties if you want your images to always be at the ends of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity and Layout gravity properties to set it..